# Printing the locale names

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nslocale

I want to know and print the locale names which I am changing on my device. Is there any way to print them. Printing a NSLocale object does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `NSLocale` for the language in which you want the words to appear, then use `-displayNameForKey:value:` on the `NSLocale` object to get the display name for the `NSLocaleIdentifier` key.

The documentation for this method has an example that shows you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It worked. Thanks... but here I had to give my own values... like fr_FR and en_US. I was thinking if there is a way to directly print locale names from the NSLocale object. Because if from device I have chosen the French locale but in code I am trying to print with en_US, a wrong locale name is being printed.